# OpenSuse does not show .eps files

Tags: linux, opensuse

I am running on this machine on a cluster:

```
> lsb_release -r -i -c -d
Distributor ID: openSUSE project
Description:    openSUSE 13.2 (Harlequin) (x86_64)
Release:    13.2
Codename:   Harlequin
```

And it happens now that, when I create '.eps' files they are not shown in the folders, while they are in a terminal 'ls -l' command. Permissions are the same as the other files in the same folder, which are visualized correctly. Even if a check the 'Show hidden files' option, nothing changes.

Any idea about the reason? It is quite annoying!

EDIT:

My desktop:

> echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
>
> gnome

Comment: What desktop or file manager are you using? KDE (dolphin), Gnome (nautilus), LXDE (pcmanfm)?

Comment: gnome. I added it as an edit to the original message.